# command not found when using sudo ulimit

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-12.04

I was using ubuntu 12.04 ,on which I run ulimit -n ,it is showing 1024,
I want to increase my open file limit from 1024 to 65535,so I tried the following command:

```
sudo ulimit -n 65535
```

but i get the following error:

```
sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

How to increase the file limit from 1024 to 65535? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question is useful for mongodb, added that tag.

Comment: New question on unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81843/sudo-ulimit-command-not-found

Answer (score 126):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin like `cd`, not a separate program. `sudo` looks for a binary to run, but there is no `ulimit` binary, which is why you get the error message.

You have a few options:

1. On newer linux versions, there is usually a `prlimit` command which
   *is* a binary, meaning you can `sudo` it if needed.

   Run

   ```
   prlimit --pid=$$ --nofile=65000:
   ```

   to increase the soft limit for the current shell. `$$` is magic that
   gets interpreted as, “the process id of the current shell.”

   If that command complains about “Operation not permitted,” `sudo prlimit` will work in most cases.

   ```
   sudo prlimit --pid=$$ --nofile=65000
   ```

   If you still get “Operation not permitted” with `sudo`, you might be
   running into some other kernel limit, like exceeding the max allowable
   limit.
2. You used to be able to rely on running

   ```
   sudo sh -c "ulimit -n 65535 && exec su $LOGNAME"
   ```

   and that may still work on older linux installs. It will give you a new
   shell, without root privileges, but with the raised limit. The `exec`
   causes the new shell to replace the process with `sudo` privileges, so
   after you exit that shell, you won’t accidentally end up as root again.

   However this doesn’t seem to work reliably on newer (2022+?) distros,
   where `su` re-applies the default limits.

   The `prlimit` approach is much better though as you don’t have the
   security concern of running a root shell, or a process that was forked
   from a root shell. If you are desperate a risky variant that seems to
   work on newer distros is the monstrosity `sudo -E sh -c "ulimit -n 65000 && exec setpriv --reuid=$(id -u) --regid=$(id -g) --inh-caps=-all --groups=$(groups|tr ' ' ,) -- env USER=\"$USER\" LOGNAME=\"$LOGNAME\" \"$SHELL\" --login"`.

   However option #1 is far simpler, much less risky from a security
   perspective, and you should definitely use it if available.

Comment: Slight tweak worked perfect for me:
sudo sh -c "ulimit -u 1000000 && ulimit -n 100000 && exec su $LOGNAME"

Comment: Note that this makes one loose env for user.

Comment: Thanks. Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446539/how-can-i-change-my-command-to-run-without-superuser-privilleges-but-with-the-ch?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Actually I don't understand yet how `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"` can solve any problem.

Comment: Thanks. Another explanation https://gist.github.com/ntamvl/017ce61db2d3c6b9c595f2fac8eeac3c

Answer (score 0):

I've had to deal with issues like this in the past.  Since there is no setuid mechanism for shell scripts (because it's insecure), I've found writing a simple C wrapper with a setuid is suffice and then using a system call to modify the ulimits of the running process before dropping privileges and executing your shell script.